# counter variable in xslt for each

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

Can anyone please advice how can I have value of i in the following XSLT code please?

```
<xsl:for-each select="MenuItems/mainmenu">
<xsl:variable name="i" select="position()"/>     
      <li class="menu_hover" onclick="SwitchMenu(this, $i)" >
 </li>    
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the short cut for 'value-of' which is the curly braces:

```
<xsl:for-each select="MenuItems/mainmenu">
<xsl:variable name="i" select="position()"/>     
  <li class="menu_hover" onclick="SwitchMenu(this, {$i})" >
 </li>    
</xsl:for-each>
```